# Set Portal from @gorhom/portal as View using mock in jest

Tags: react-native, jestjs

I would like to Mock using jest the component `<Portal />` from `@gorhom/portal` as a View.

I would like to do it because the `<Portal />` component require a `<PortalProvider />` at the root of the app. But I would like to test a single screen.

This is the mock that I've done:

```
import { jest } from '@jest/globals'

jest.mock('@gorhom/portal', () => {
  const react = require('react-native')

  return {
    __esModule: true,
    Portal: () => react.View,
    usePortal: jest.fn(),
  }
})
```

This is the test I am running

```
import React from 'react'

import renderer from 'react-test-renderer'

import ViewWithPortal from 'screens/ViewWithPortal'

test('renders correctly', () => {
  expect(true).toBeTruthy()

  const tree = renderer.create(<ViewWithPortal />).toJSON()
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot()
})
```

But when I call in my test my screen this is the error I have:

```
'PortalDispatchContext' cannot be null, please add 'PortalProvider' to the root component.

       7 |
       8 | test('renders correctly', () => {
    >  9 |   const tree = renderer.create(<CreateAccount />).toJSON()
         |                         ^
      10 |   expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot()
      11 | })
      12 |
```

And the component causing the issue is this one:

```
const ViewWithPortal = () => {

  ...

  return (
    <Portal>
      <BottomSheet>
        {...}
      </BottomSheet>
    </Portal>
  )
}
```

If you have any tips!

Comment: @imasneri, It Looks like the component hierarchy(one of its children) is using the PortalDispatchContext using `useContext(PortalDispatchContext.context)`. Have you checked it? Even though you are mocking the Portal, i think some where the children are trying to access the context.

Comment: What should I do @Gavara.Suneel ? Mock PortalDispatchContext ?

Comment: Yes., before that could you tell me somewhere are you using  `useContext(PortalDispatchContext.context)`? If it is, yes you have to mock it.

Comment: I tried mocking PortalDispatchContext as so `PortalDispatchContext: () => {}` but not working, and I am using the `<PortalProvider`> just inside my `App.tsx` at the top level (PortalProvider is the provider to permit Portal to work but as I am trying it with jest there is no PortalProvider, that is why I have the error).

Comment: @Gavara.Suneel I have edited my question so that you can see the jest test

Comment: Got it. We can consider two causes for failures here. The first one is one of the children inside `<Portal><<BottomSheet>{...}</BottomSheet>></Portal>` is still using the PortalDispatchContext. If not, the second case is jest is not taking the mock into consideration. Please check once.

Comment: I will check first one but it is most likely the second issue. Do you know why it is not taking it into consideration ?

Comment: @Gavara.Suneel Nothing call `PortalDispatchContext` inside my component, so it is just not mocking `<Portal>` into `<View>` for some reason

Comment: @iamsneri., Have you added the mock file path into setup files or other configurations where jest would search for all the mock paths?

Comment: @Gavara.Suneel yes...

Comment: And I've added `@gorhom/portal` in my `transformIgnorePatterns` in my jest.config.js

Comment: @Gavara.Suneel I've found why........ my `ViewWithPortal` is from another repository because im working in a mono repo, and I was mocking the node_modules from the repo I was testing and not the repo that was calling the `Portal`

Comment: And also I would suggest you add the above mock at your test file level and check once. If it is working, then there is an issue with the jest when it is picking mock files.

Comment: So Is the issue resolved? Is it due to the in correct path picked by jest?

Comment: Yes that what I've done to realise that my import wasn't working, it was due to the monorepo, I should have thought about it. Thank you for your help!

Comment: That's great to hear. Could you please accept and upvote my answer as you are able to solve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the issue is with the jest which is not picking up the path of your mock file. Please check whether this path is added to mock paths or if you are running the tests in the correct directory.